# Как вычислить размерность колонки bootstarp

Tags: javascript

Никак не получается написать функцию, которая на выходе выдает массив чисел, соответствующие размерности колонки в bootstrap.

На вход функции задается кол-во текущих колонок (col), например 7 (макс 12). В результате функция должна выдать размерность каждой колонки, распределив на 7 колонок на 12: [2,2,2,2,2,1,1].

Как это реализовать не догоняю. Может у кого мысли есть?

Comment: колонки то минимального размера должны быть, или какие?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я вам, как ни странно, предложу способ решения вашей задачи, который просто максимально гибок в настройке, чрезвычайно понятен даже начинающим разработчиком, и поэтому его поддержка требует минимальных затрат. глядите:

```
function makeCols(num){
   swith(num){
      case 12: return [1,1,1, 1,1,1, 1,1,1, 1,1,1]; 
      ....
      case 7:  return [2,2,2, 2,1,1];
      ....
      case 4:  return [3,3,3,3];
      case 3:  return [4,4,4];
      case 2:  return [6,6];
      case 1:  return [12];
      default:  throw new RangeError();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно так:

```js
const maxCol = 12;
const numCol = 7;


function getColumnsSizes(numCol, maxCol) {
  const arr = [];
  const ceil = Math.floor(maxCol / numCol);
  const residue = maxCol % numCol;
  for (let i = 0; i < numCol; i++) {
    i < residue ? arr.push(ceil + 1) : arr.push(ceil)
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(getColumnsSizes(numCol, maxCol))
```

Актуально для разных размеров

Comment: попробуйте для некой красоты вариант с `Array(numCol).map(...)` чтобы без пушей было.